# Resizing UIView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, sdk

I am trying to resize a UIView instance that is part of the tapjoy SDK.

here is the code:

```
- (UIView*)showFeaturedAppFullScreenAd:(NSString*)adURL withFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    UIView *fullScreenAdView = nil;

    [self moveViewToFront];

    [self.view setAlpha:1];

    fullScreenAdView = [TJCFeaturedAppViewHandler showFullScreenAdWithURL:adURL withFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:fullScreenAdView];

    return fullScreenAdView;
}
```

I tried adding my own setter method in the above method:

```
fullScreenAdView.frame = CGRectOffset(fullScreenAdView.frame, 50, 500);
```

But it had no effect on the tapjoy ad when I ran it.

My question is this: I am trying to resize this instance so that instead of taking up 100% of the device window, it takes up (let's say) 70%.

I have some ideas how to do this, but they're vague (such as writing fullScreenAdView = [mainScreen * 0.7f), but I was hoping someone would have some more concrete ideas.

edit: here's a super, high-tech picture of what my situation is. 
http://i207.photobucket.com/albums/bb289/teh_Mac/tjAd-1.jpg

This is the proto-method I have come up with so far:

```
fullScreenAdView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, [mainScreen * 0.7f], [mainScreen * 0.7f];
```

Comment: Why not use "fullsScreenAdView.frame = self.view.bounds"?

Comment: how is that going to let me 'shrink' the UIView instance to the size I want?

Comment: What do you mean shrink?  Your question says you want the 'ad' to cover the whole screen.  To shrink it, wouldn't it be a matter of using CGRectMake instead of CGRectOffset?  It seems strange that you would use CGRectOffset.

Comment: The CGRectOffset was me trying to create some kind of effect on the Ad--it had no effect whatsoever. Which makes me think that the code I wrote is in limbo and has no effect. 
Yes, I want to try CGRectMake but I am not sure how to effectively integrate that code...that is the purpose of this thread

Comment: Ah!  CGRectMake has 4 parameters.  The first two set the x and y of the origin respectively.  Origin (0,0) for example is the top left of the screen, then everything would extend to the right and the bottom.  The final two parameters are a height and a width.  If you want to animate the effect, put a CGRectMake change in a [UIView animateWithDuration:animations]; block.

Comment: that's exactly what I am looking for. However, here's where it gets tricky. Because I am pretty much trying to optimize for iphones iOS 4.0+ and iPads, these guys all have varying resolutions. 
So, I like the percentage route.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6539/discussion-between-gpp-and-codafi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use CGRectMake and make it a percentage of the superview?

```
float percentage = .7f;  //whatever you like
int xPosition = fullScreenAdView.superview.frame.size.width * ((1 - percentage) / 2);
int yPosition = fullScreenAdView.superview.frame.size.height * ((1 - percentage) / 2);

int width = fullScreenAdView.superview.frame.size.width * (1 - percentage);
int height = fullScreenAdView.superview.frame.size.height * (1 - percentage);

fullScreenAdView.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
```

This is written off the top of my head, but I think with a little tweaking it would do what you want.

Comment: hey, thanks for the awesome answer! Unfortunately, after testing this code, I dont think the method I listed is responsible for frame scale. 

This is because I tested another method further up the code:
- (UIView*)showFeaturedAppFullScreenAdWithURL:(NSString*)adURL
{
 return [self showFeaturedAppFullScreenAd:adURL withFrame:self.view.frame]; //replaced bounds w/ frame
}

And it changed the UIView, but the modifications I made to the method listed in my question had no effect; just to repeat myself, I tested this by commenting out the fullScreenAdView.frame....

And it had no effect.

Comment: Completely worked for me. Thought I just need to set the bounds, but the frame was what I was missing!